# Why can't I save encrypted data in a transient?

Tags: transient, encryption

I'm trying to save encrypted data (using AES-256-CBC in PHP) in a transient but for some reason it keeps failing. The transient key is under the required length of 45 characters and the data is not a huge amount to go over the longtext size. I tried doing in manually in phpmyadmin and it works, it is something with how WordPress is seeing the data. Any ideas?

```
function encrypt_text( $text ){
  $textToEncrypt = $text;
  $encryptionMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';  // AES is used by the U.S. gov't to encrypt top secret documents.
  $secretHash = 'secrethashgoeshere';
  $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length( $encryptionMethod );
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( $iv_size );
  $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt( $textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $iv );
  $encryptedMessage = $iv.$encryptedMessage; // Add the IV to the beginning of the encrypted string.
  return $encryptedMessage;
}

function decrypt_text( $encryptedValue ){
    $encryptionMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';  // AES is used by the U.S. gov't to encrypt top secret documents.
    $secretHash = 'secrethashgoeshere';
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length( $encryptionMethod );
    $iv = substr( $encryptedValue, 0, $iv_size ); // Retrieve the IV that was appended to the begining of the encrypted string.
    $decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt( substr( $encryptedValue, $iv_size ), $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $iv );
    return $decryptedMessage;
}
```

And I use the transients API like this to set it:

```
$json_contact_info = json_encode( $contact_info );
$transient_data =  encrypt_text( $json_contact_info );
$transient_array = array( 'data' => $transient_data );
$transient_set = set_transient( $transient_name, $transient_array, 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 );
```

And like this to get it:

```
$decrypted_transient_data = decrypt_text( $transient_data );
$cr_json = json_decode( $decrypted_transient_data );
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to answer the question when you don't show your code? In any case most likely it is a problem with how you use the encryption api

Comment: The encryption part works fine, I can encrypt and de-crypt without a problem. The issue is not with encryption, it is with WordPress not saving it to the database.

Comment: Any ideas now @MarkKaplun ?

Comment: do you have object caching on, in that case they are not stored in the DB? what happens if you save as an option instead of transient, did you try to read the value immidiatly after setting it?

Comment: I'm using VVV, so there is object caching. But if you try to check the $transient_set value (which is true if the transient is saved) it is false so it doesn't matter if I check the value I know it is not saved because the $transient_set value would be true if that was the case.

Comment: therefor the problem is most likely with your object cache implementation

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to use base64_encode and base64_decode.

So basically doing something like this to set the transient:

```
$json_contact_info = json_encode( $contact_info );
$transient_data =  encrypt_text( $json_contact_info );
$transient_array = base64_encode( $transient_data );
$transient_set = set_transient( $transient_name, $transient_array, 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 );
```

And then to get the transient:

```
$decrypted_transient_data = decrypt_text( base64_decode( $transient_data ) );
$cr_json = json_decode( $decrypted_transient_data );
```

Comment: And you said the problem is not with the encryption itself ;) leaving the zero character in a string is always an invitation for trouble with libraries based on C code.

Comment: The encryption did work fine without base64, WP just didn't save the transient with that format. Thanks for your input on this though.